# Is there a guideline or a set of expectations for how well-sourced Answers should be?

Tags: discussion

I'm a very new user.

- Is there a guideline or a general set of expectations somewhere for how well-sourced Answers should be?

As a new user, the expectations weren't clear that this site is meant for specifically scientific or academic discussion (or, rather, Q&A), if it is that.  And if it is supposed to be that, how much it is supposed to be?

I did the introductory "2-minute site tour" and searched Vegetarianism Meta for one, but couldn't find a specific answer.  [This](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95/improve-other-peoples-answers-add-scientific-references) seems to be the closest to the topic, but it is also inconclusive, saying something like (paraphrasing) "more sources make for better answers".

Does extremely general, common-knowledge-type information have to be sourced?  (Because at some level of generality, it becomes not required in academia.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, any time a claim is made I expect a source. Depending on the question, citing experience can be acceptable. In a question about cooking and substitutes for example, this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Source as much as possible.

The more sources you include, the easier it is for people to check if what you wrote is correct. The easier it is to check, the more votes you get. If you don't include sources, it sounds like you're just making things up, and that's not good. So source anything that your kid sister wouldn't know, to be on the safe side. More sources *always* improves the answer ;)